# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Cache' not found in Prestashop

Tags: caching, prestashop, classnotfound

I am working width prestashop 1.0. I am facing this issue when i delete the cache folder but i have reupload it but it is solving. if any guys have faced such kind of problem, please suggest me that how i resolve it.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Cache' not found in /customers/a/2/e/sekuurshop.be/httpd.www/classes/ObjectModel.php:1924 Stack trace: #0 /customers/a/2/e/sekuurshop.be/httpd.www/classes/ObjectModel.php(214): ObjectModelCore::getDefinition('Shop') #1 /customers/a/2/e/sekuurshop.be/httpd.www/classes/shop/Shop.php(130): ObjectModelCore->__construct('1', NULL, NULL) #2 /customers/a/2/e/sekuurshop.be/httpd.www/classes/shop/Shop.php(411): ShopCore->__construct('1') #3 /customers/a/2/e/sekuurshop.be/httpd.www/config/config.inc.php(117): ShopCore::initialize() #4 /customers/a/2/e/sekuurshop.be/httpd.www/index.php(27): require('/customers/a/2/...') #5 {main} thrown in /customers/a/2/e/sekuurshop.be/httpd.www/classes/ObjectModel.php on line 1924
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have delated your complete cache folder. Upload folder from local server if exist. Because sometime prestashop doesn't create cache folder itself once deleted like others.

Hope it may help you.